# Result is with the time format 2:15:59 PM but expected 14:15:59

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am not pro to VB net so my question is probably newbies...
I have problem to convert my string to datetime, here's my portion of code:

```
Dim aaa = DateTime.ParseExact("20160409 141559", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

the result is with the time format 2:15:59 PM but expected  14:15:59

Comment: The result is a DateTime instance which doesn't have a "format" - what you see is just the representation you see in your Visual Studio locals/watch/debugger. If you decide to render a string representation of your `aaa` DateTime instance you will be able to give it the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your result aaa into a date that suits you.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20160409 141559", "yyyyMMdd HHmmss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss")
```

To get the result of 14:15 then use the code above and add any semicolons you need inside the `ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss")` function.